# How does (i)+ (++i) {for i=1} becomes 4 and not 3?

Tags: c++

how does my output come to be as 4 and not 3 in:

```
int i=1;
int k;

k=i + ++i;
cout<<k<<endl;
```

So, according to me what happens here is that the first i must be 1 and the (++i) must be 2.
So, when they both are added the value of k must be 3 right?
Ofcourse I'm missing something. But what?

Comment: Where's the `for` loop?

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "sequence points".

Comment: You don't know if it will be as if `++i; k = i + i;` or `k = i; ++i; k += i;`.

Comment: Please help me find a proper duplicate (C++, the currently linked one is C)

Comment: Today must be Increment Operator Day on Stackoverflow. This is like the third substantively identical question that got dupe-hammered.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: That's a slightly different case, here the object is only modified once, but there is a read unordered with respect to the modification.

Comment: @BenVoigt Agree - I removed the comment.

Comment: [The compiler output](https://godbolt.org/z/KKsn3E8EM) with enough warnings turned on may be helpful